# Thread abruptly getting killed during execution

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a controller in java which calls a service responsible for heavy tasks of 100s of external calls, aggregating data from all these calls, processing them and finally emailing the data in a csv format.

Since there are a lot of external calls, the time taken for complete process is large. So I have created a thread and handed over this task to that thread to execute and the main thread exits immediately.

```
    Runnable task = () -> {
        try {
            service.createReport(startTime, endTime);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.setPriority(10);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(thread);
    executor.shutdown();
```

The issue here is that the user thread that I created starts executing and calling external apis and due to some reason it abruptly terminates and that too WITHOUT any error/exception.
It just stops in between of calling all the external Apis as I can see in the logs.
Also, when I execute this for a short period of time when there will be less external calls, It executes successfully.

Requesting help!!

Comment: Please provide [mre]

Comment: rather than catching IOException, can you try catching Exception to catch all the possible Exception?

Comment: Why are you calling executor.shutdown()?

Comment: @OliverStahl: all `shutDown()` does is prevent the executor service from accepting *new* tasks and is an appropriate method to call when you want to make sure that the service behaves this way, and which is appropriate in this current situation.

Comment: @OliverStahl In general, the ExecutorService will not be automatically destroyed when there is not task to process. It will stay alive and wait for new tasks to do. It simply means that JVM will not terminate if we are expecting it to be. So to prevent that, shutdown is used.

Comment: It could be OutOfMemoryError. You can enable GC logs and watch if memory consumption reaches limit.

Comment: Why are you giving a `Thread` instance to the executor? Why don't you just give the `task` to the executor?

Comment: @SolomonSlow I had also tried giving the runnable task directly to the executor instead of the thread instance but still it has the same issue. Also, the thread is abruptly terminated during the execution. It is not the case that the worker thread did not start even. The worker thread starts the execution and in the course of the process, it stops without any error or exception.

Comment: Oops! I mixed up `shutDown()` with `shutDownNow()`—I thought it would discard tasks that had been submitted but not yet started. Comment deleted.

Comment: Just for completeness, how do you know that the thread "terminates...WITHOUT any error?" Obviously, if `createReport(...)` threw an `IOException`, your code would log that, but what about `Error`s? Have you tried setting the [uncaught exception handler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) for the thread? NOTE: You won't be able to do that using `newSingleThreadExecutor`. You'll have to create a naked `Thread`, as I suggested in my non-answer answer (below).

Answer (score 0):

This really should be a comment, not an answer, but I can't format code in a comment.

Why do you create a thread *pool* when you only want to perform a single task? Why not simply do this instead?

```java
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        service.createReport(startTime, endTime);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
)};
thread.start();
```

---

On the other hand, if the program is going to *frequently* perform the same task, then it might make sense to keep a thread pool alive instead of creating and destroying a new one for every invocation of the task:

```java
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
...
executor.submit(() -> {
    try {
        service.createReport(startTime, endTime);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. In the beginning I Infact did this. But this too did not work so shifted to executors. I have also replied to your comment. Please have a look.